# prove that ${3^{3n}} + 3^{2n} + 3^{n } + 1$ is divided by $4$. by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

I tried to take the 3 out but it is not helping me much. [image: My try]

Comment: have you tried modular arithmetic? and you can ask in hebrew in chat if you want

Comment: אין לי מושג איך עוברים לצ'אט!! תסביר לי בבקשההה @friedvir

Comment: אממ פעם ראשונה שאני מנסה האמת, אבל תכתבי בחיפוש צ'אט ונראה

Comment: אני חושבת שאם כותבים פה הרבה רק אז זה מעביר לצ'אט

Comment: לא, אבל לא משנה אני אסביר ככה.. מספיק להוכיח שכל הביטוי של השלוש בחזקת משהו מתחלק בשלושת, והפלוס אחד יגרום לזה להתחלק ב4

Comment: איך אני מוכיחה את זה @friedvir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99504/discussion-between-lorin-sherry-and-friedvir).

Comment: Not proof by induction, but it is just $(3^{2n}+1)(3^n+1)$, a product of two even numbers, hence divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 4):

$$...= 3^{2n}(3^n+1)+(3^n+1)= (3^{2n}+1)(3^n+1)$$

Notice that $(3^{2n}+1)$ and $(3^n+1)$ are even, so you are done.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. The proposition that you want to prove using induction is $$P(n): 4\mid \underbrace{3^{3n}+3^{2n}+3^n +1}_{:=a_n}$$
It is easy to check that $P(0)$ holds. Assume that $P(n)$ holds for some integer $n\ge 0$ (that is, $a_n$ is a multiple of $4$) and consider $$a_{n+1}=27\cdot 3^{3n}+9\cdot 3^{2n}+3\cdot 3^n+1=3a_n+24\cdot 3^n +6 \cdot3^{2n}-2.$$
Notice that $3a_n$ and $24\cdot 3^n$ are clearly multiples of $4$. Also $$6 \cdot3^{2n}-2 = 2\underbrace{(3^{2n}-1)}_{\text{even}} $$
is a multiple of $4$. Therefore, $a_{n+1}$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Hey thank you! but why An+1 is equal to 3an +.. etc ? why 3an is there

Comment: I dont understand what come after the equal sign

Comment: $a_{n+1}= 3(3^{3n}+3^{2n}+3^n+1)+24\cdot 3^n +6 \cdot3^{2n}-2$, I hope that this answers your first question. About your 2nd question: which equal sign are you talking about?

Comment: Ive got it thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
3^0 \equiv +1 \bmod 4
\\
3^1 \equiv -1 \bmod 4
\\
3^2 \equiv +1 \bmod 4
\\
3^3 \equiv -1 \bmod 4
\\
$$
Therefore, $3^{3n}+3^{2n}+3^{n} + 1 \equiv 1^n +(-1)^n + 1^n + (-1)^n \equiv 0 \bmod 4$.

Answer (score 1):

By induction?

Well if we assume $3^{3n} + 3^{2n} + 3^n + 1= 4K$ then

$3^{3(n+1)} +3^{2(n+1)} + 3^{n+1} + 1=$

$3^{3n+3} + 3^{2n + 2} + 3^{n+1} + 1=$

$3^{3n}*27 + 3^{2n}*9 + 3^n*3 + 1 =$

$[3^{3n} + 3^{2n} + 3^n+1] + 26*3^{3n} + 8*3^{2n} + 2*3^n =$

$4K + 4(6*3^{2n} + 2*3^{2n}) + 2(3^{3n} + 3^n) =$

$4[K+(6*3^{2n} + 2*3^{2n})] + 2*3^{n}(3^{2n} + 1)=$

$4[K+(6*3^{2n} + 2*3^{2n})] + 4*3^{n}*\frac {3^{2n} + 1}2$.

The only thing left to prove is that $3^{2n} + 1$ is even and.... c'mon.....!

Comment: the 4K need to be minus no? because it was over the equal sign

Comment: "the 4K need to be minus no? because it was over the equal sign "  ?????????? The $4K$ is $3^{3n} + 3^{2n} + 3^n + 1$ which is positive but I don't see that it makes any difference.  I'm not solving or manipulating any equation so I'm not "subtracting $4K$ from both sides" so... no.  It should not be minus.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=3^{3n}+3^{2n}+3^{n} + 1 = (3^3)^n+(3^2)^n+(3^1)^n + (3^0)^n$.
Since 
$$(x-3^3)(x-3^2)(x-3^1)(x-3^0)= x^4 - 40 x^3 + 390 x^2 - 1080 x + 729$$
we have
$$
a_{n+4} =40 a_{n+3} - 390 a_{n+2} + 1080 a_{n+1} - 729a_{n}
$$
The claim that $a_n$ is a multiple of $4$ for all $n$ follows by induction since it is true for $n=0,1,2,3$.

(The actual coefficients in that recurrence do not matter. It only matters that they are integers.)

Comment: Your answer seems perfect to me just a little thing - why 3^3n is equal according to you to (x-3^3) ?

Comment: @LorinSherry, I don't understand your question. The point is that if $u$ is a root of that polynomial, then $u^4 = 40 u^3 - 390 u^2 + 1080 u - 729$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Your expression is a geometric series $$\frac{3^{4n}-1}{3-1}$$

You also have that $$3^{4n}=(4-1)^{4n}=\sum_{i=0}^{4n}\binom{4n}{i}4^i(-1)^{4n-i}$$